# Project Management/Tracker software - to replace Redmine

Tags: project-management, redmine

I am using Redmine and as a free software it is more than good.
But I'm facing some problems now and I'm looking for some system to replace Redmine.
Main disadvantages from my point of view are:

- hard installation - My version is 1.3.1 (installation process was pain in the @$$), now when I want to upgrade to 2.*.* I can see in the site that this will be pain too
- not so stable - (using stand-alone nginx server) there are some problems like sometimes cannot upload files until restart passenger, stopped working two times (passenger process missing for some reason) etc
- my last attempt to set-up a plugin was unsuccessful
- I'm not Ruby developer and it's hard to maintain the Redmine - I'm pretty not sure what are the security issues, how to use Redmine with already installed SSL on one of the domains (port 80) etc

So I'm looking for a new system (preferred /but not mandatory/ option to be NOT SaaS) with these features:

Required:

- Project management
- Bug Tracking
- Possibility to generate Invoices (as a plugin is cool too)
- User friendly interface

Good to have:

- openID login
- not necessarily free (but for a reasonable price)
- if it's not SaaS - to be PHP based, not Ruby, Python, Java etc

I have some experience with Assembla, Pivotal, Yodiz and Mantis.

Yodiz interface is too complex and not clean for me.

Mantis is like from the past (looks like the first tracker ever)

Pivotal is not so bad, but I think is best for issues tracking only (not project management, invoices etc)

Assembla.. very little experience, only for SVN

I know there are lots of discussions, the problem is that many people liked Redmine for some reasons that are totally opposite of my opinion.
I'm spending some time last 2 days to review most popular trackers, but with no success so far.

I'll try "Trac" now, but will be glad if someone share it's experience with this popular Trac problem - multiple projects. :)

Thanks!

Comment: Inside of Redmine, which version control system are you using? I see that Redmine offers SVN, CVS, Git, Mercurial, Bazaar and Darcs.

Comment: I'm using SVN and it works good.

Comment: It would be interesting if you described exactly what was so difficult about installing Redmine and plugins, as I have not had any such trouble. Never saw the stability issue, although I'm using it with Apache, not Nginx. Frankly, Redmine is pretty easy as things go so I suspect you'll run into the same problems with anything else that isn't a SaaS fully managed for you. As for Ruby, it's a valid point, but unless you're writing custom plugins <exaggeration>all you really need to know about Ruby is "bundle install"</exaggeration>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I found needed software.

[FengOffice](http://www.fengoffice.com/web/) seems to fit my requirements very well.

- [community version](http://www.fengoffice.com/web/community/downloads.php) (free)
- self hosted (2 minutes installation)
- written on PHP
- very good UI - I like the way it's organized, AJAX UI is very good implemented in this case
- cool features

.. etc

I don't have more detailed impressions, but it looks really promising.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to take a look at assembla. It is not for SVN only - you can use git / svn / mercurial tools or even add external github tool.

Project management for assembla recently got much better (with implementation of Planner and Cardwall) and new improvements are planned.

If you track your hours in commit messages or web interface, it is very easy to export the working hours (to generate an invoice)

Comment: Once upon a time, assembla itself was forked from redmine.

Answer (score 0):

The current Trac version (1.0) does not natively provide multi-project support, although there is some discussion about that topic in the Trac wiki. But since Trac 0.12 there is a plugin [SimpleMultiProjectPlugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/SimpleMultiProjectPlugin) that extends Trac with the feature 'multiple projects in one installed Trac instance'.

A good description of what that Trac plugin SimpleMultiProjectPlugin exactly provides can be read [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en&fromgroups#!searchin/trac-users/SimpleMultiProject%2420x%2420Milestone%2420-%2420How%2420to%2420Use/trac-users/cJkSp-SG1gc/Al8zpHwTN0EJ) or on the plugin wiki page (see link above).